# More elegant way to create a list of 2D points in Python

Tags: python, list, 2d

I need to create a list of 2D points (x,y) in python. 
This will do it

```
l = []

for x in range (30,50,5):
    for y in range (1,10,3):
        l.append((x,y))
```

So: `print l` will produce:

```
[(30, 1), (30, 4), (30, 7), (35, 1), (35, 4), (35, 7), (40, 1), (40, 4), (40, 7), (45, 1), (45, 4), (45, 7)]
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 13):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product
l = list(product(range(30,50,5), range(1,10,3)))
```

It scales better and should be faster than a generator expression, list comprehension, or explicit loops.

Answer (score 8):

```
l = [(x,y) for x in range(30,50,5) for y in range(1,10,3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> l = list((x, y) for x in range(30, 50, 5) for y in range(1, 10, 3))
>>> l
[(30, 1), (30, 4), (30, 7), (35, 1), (35, 4), (35, 7), (40, 1), (40, 4), (40, 7), (45, 1), (45, 4), (45, 7)]
```

Comment: No point using generator expression if you just convert it to a list.

Comment: @srgerg: out of curiosity - why pass a generator expression to `list()` instead of using a list comprehension?

Comment: According to the python documentation linked to in my answer "Generator expressions ... tend to be more memory friendly than equivalent list comprehensions."

Comment: @Dikei Yes, if the result of the generator expression is converted to a list then this just becomes a list comprehension. I converted it to list because the question asked for a list result and because it enabled me to display the result of the expression. It may be possible for the OP to remove the conversion to list and use the more efficient generator expression in their own code, but without more contextual information I can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks. I think this solution is good. I'm just switching to Python from C++ so want to learn to do things "pythonically". I just need to generate a list of pixel locations to process in an image.  I use a list because the results of this processing will generate an ordered list that will then be analyzed, pruned, sorted with the result being a list of indices indicating the pixels you "want" in the original list.